# Variables in the measure column

Tags: spss

This may sound a simple question but I just want to confirm. Is ID of participants continuous, nominal or ordinal data?

Comment: It is a perfectly reasonable question. Can you provide some context for this? I'm wondering why you would want to know / what you would do with the information. There is no problem with answering this, but I am suspecting that there is going to be something more we should clear up.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the ID variable encodes some substantive information, it is surely nominal.  However, the automatic measurement level assignment heuristics in Statistics might assign a scale level because of the large number of values.  Since you are presumably not going to use this for any substantive purpose, the ML really doesn't matter.